# Package e1071/RTextTools: object "results_table" not found in R

Tags: r, text-mining

I am trying to perform some text classification through R and the package RTextTools (also with tm).

I have coded almost everything, but in the end, an error appears and says this:

*SVmodel <- train_model(container, SVM)*

*svm_emails <- classify_model(container, SVmodel)*

*Error in classify_model(container, SVM) : object "results_table" not found*

Please note that SVmodel is not a string but an object, so I do not know what is going on with the "results_table", a list I do not even know in my code.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you try `train_model(container, "SVM")`?

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Reproducibility.html).

Comment: library(RTextTools)
data <- read.table('Data Prueba.csv', sep=";", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(data)
dtMatrix <- create_matrix(data["Text"])
container <- create_container(dtMatrix, data$IsSunny, trainSize = 1:11, virgin=FALSE)
model <- train_model(container, "SVM", kernel="linear", cost=1)
results <- classify_model(container,predMatrix)
predictionData <- list("sunny sunny sunny rainy rainy", "rainy sunny rainy rainy", "hello", "", "this is another rainy world")
predMatrix <- create_matrix(predictionData, originalMatrix = dtMatrix)
results ##Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `classify_model` function expects a single model, whereas the `train_model` function returns a list of trained models (of length 1; strange as there is a separate `train_models` function).
To pass the model from the list, you can use the `$` operator:

`SVmodel <- train_model(container, SVM)
svm_emails <- classify_model(container, SVmodel$SVM)`

Hope this helps!